# BPM Analyze iOS

Tags: ios

I want to allow the user to play songs from his\her song list on the device and in real time give them the BPM.

I saw SoundTouch but I think its a overkill for me, I just need something simple.

Comment: visit : //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657073/how-to-detect-bpm-of-the-song-by-programming