# AVAudioPlayer rate to BPM conversion

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to set allow my users to set a BPM of a AVAudioPlayer, from what I see the rate property of AVAudioPlayer should be the one I want to alter if I'm changing the frequency of a player. My question is, if I were to present it as a BPM setting, is there an easy way to convert from BPM to rate? For example, .8 rate == 120BPM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to know the BPM of the track at normal speed. When you have that, you can convert with

newBPM = normalBPM x rate

Say at normal speed the track is 120 BPM

Then at 0.5 speed it will be 120 x 0.5 = 60 BPM

At double speed (rate = 2) it will be 120 x 2.0 = 240 BPM

If you don't know the BPM of a track at normal speed you will need to do some more in-depth audio processing with beat-detection algorithms:

[How to detect the BPM of a song in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657073/how-to-detect-bpm-of-the-song-by-programming)

If you want to avoid pitch shifting when changing the audio rate, you will also need to check out [time stretching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_timescale-pitch_modification)

Using such algorithms is beyond the scope of AVAudioPlayer - you will need to look at lower-level Core Audio functions (Audio Queues / Audio Units)

Comment: @0x7fffffff +1 your comment - tx!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any relation between BPM and the rate property of the AVAudioPlayer. For example, [relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/rate) states:

> This property’s default value of 1.0 provides normal playback rate.
>   The available range is from 0.5 for half-speed playback through 2.0
>   for double-speed playback.

So as far as I can tell, this means that you would need to know the BPM of the track going in. (If you know how to get this great, I personally couldn't tell you) Then, reguardless of what the BPM is, if the rate is 1 playback will continue at the default BPM. If rate is .5 then playback will be half BPM and if rate is 2, then playback will be double BPM.