# Android analyze song

Tags: android

I have a problem, I searched and searched but didn't find the right thing or something what can help me. So I hope I will find here my answer and help.

For what I exactly search is, that I want to now if there exists a library which analyze a song "mp3" or other song format on the android device, and gives me all the information of a song back, like the bpm. And maybe a real time analyzing so that I know, ok this tone is a high tone, and the next tone a low tone.

I hope you can understand for what I search, and maybe anyone can help me to give me some hint how I can realize that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an Android library that does bpm detection but there are many algorithms already discussed on [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657073/how-to-detect-bpm-of-the-song-by-programming)

For high and low tone in realtime consider using the [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) API. This has a call to give you back the FFT of the currently playing audio which you can then examine for power in various frequency ranges.

Comment: Ok I looked at the visualizer API before, but I had problems to load a song into the visualizer API to see the frequency :/ Do you know a good example which explains me the right usage of the visualizer API?