# c: music - beat detection algorithm

Tags: c, math

Is there a free library for a beat detection algorithm in C 
or any code that may assist me in performing this task?

it's needed for a new dj software I'm working on.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477944/bpm-audio-detection-library