# Returning shell_exec as string PHP detecting BPM with soundtouch/soundstrech

Tags: php, string, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I am working on a php function used to upload a .wav to server *(along with converting to mp3 and creating waveform image png*) , and within the function I would like it to use [soundtouch / soundstrech](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) to detect the B.P.M. (Beats Per Minute). I know it will not be the most accurate but for my purposes it will be all I need.

I was able to get the B.P.M. of a .wav file using [soundtouch / soundstrech](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) along with ffmpeg within a test.php file using [deven's php-bpm-detect wrapper](https://github.com/deseven/php-bpm-detect) But When I try to integrate it within my PHP function it returns the B.P.M. as zero.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to get the bpm as a string from the following shell exec without having to use a separate php library?

*I would like to perform this and have it return as a string:*

```
$song_bpm = shell_exec('soundstretch ' . $file_path . ' -bpm');
```

**test.php (This works and returns the proper bpm:)**

```
<?php
require "class.bpm.php";
$wavfile = "38a2819c20.wav";
$bpm_detect = new bpm_detect($wavfile);  
$test = $bpm_detect->detectBPM();
echo ' bpm of ' . $wavfile . ' is: ' . $test . ' ';
?>
```

**PHP Function: (returns bpm as zero)**

```
function upload_a_sound($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn, $name, $uploader, $keywords) {
    $timecode = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);
    $mp3name = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.mp3';
    $file_path = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.wav';
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $file_path . ' -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 ' . $mp3name . ''); 
    require ('classAudioFile.php'); // This creates a spectogram .png file of .wav
    $AF = new AudioFile;
    $AF->loadFile($file_path);
    $AF->visual_width=200;
    $AF->visual_height=200;
    $AF->visual_graph_color="#c491db";
    $AF->visual_background_color="#000000";
    $AF->visual_grid=false;
    $AF->visual_border=false;
    $AF->visual_graph_mode=0;
    $AF->getVisualization ('images/song/' . $timecode . '.png');
    $imageloc = 'images/song/' . $timecode . '.png';
    require ('class.bpm.php'); //Deseven's class to get bpm, 
    $bpm_detect = new bpm_detect($file_path);  
    $song_bpm = $bpm_detect->detectBPM(); //when used here this returns 0
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('', '', '$name', '$uploader', '$keywords', '$file_path', '$imageloc', '$mp3name', '$song_bpm')"); // I will update this to mysqli soon, for now it works
}
```

**I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752420/linux-command-line-php-bpm-detection) which works, but not when I integrate it into my function:**

```
// create new files, because we don't want to override the old files
$wavFile = $filename . ".wav";
$bpmFile = $filename . ".bpm";

//convert to wav file with ffmpeg
$exec = "ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i \"" . $filename . "\" -ar 32000 -ac 1 \"" . $wavFile . "\"";
$output = shell_exec($exec);

// now execute soundstretch with the newly generated wav file, write the result into a file
$exec = "soundstretch \"" . $wavFile . "\" -bpm  2> " . $bpmFile;
shell_exec($exec);

// read and parse the file 
$output = file_get_contents($bpmFile);
preg_match_all("!(?:^|(?<=\s))[0-9]*\.?[0-9](?=\s|$)!is", $output, $match);

// don't forget to delete the new generated files
unlink($wavFile);
unlink($bpmFile);

// here we have the bpm
echo $match[0][2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated [my class](https://github.com/deseven/php-bpm-detect) so it's supporting absolute and relative paths now.

And the straightforward solution:

```
exec('soundstretch "test.wav" -bpm 2>&1',$average_bpm);
foreach ($average_bpm as $line) {
    if (strpos($line,"Detected BPM rate") !== false) {
        $line = explode(" ",$line);
        $average_bpm = round($line[3]);
        break;
    }
}

echo $average_bpm;
```

Just keep in mind that `$average_bpm` will contain the error if anything goes wrong.